# Inserting div in the input JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following js:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axjw0k64/)

```
<script>
function hadd(event,which){ 
        var val = event.charCode;               
        if(val == 36){ //$ sign     
           var rh  = $(which);                           
           var cont = '<span class="dollar">Money</span>';                  
           rh.append(cont); //????      
        }           
    };  
</script>

<div class="example" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1" onkeypress="hadd(event,this);">
   Please insert (here) now  
</div>
```

When "$" is typed, it appends new `span` at the end of "Please insert (here) now".

```
Please insert ($) now money.
```

How do I append the span right after where the `$` was typed while removing the `$` sign? (see below)

```
Please insert (money) now
```

Comment: Once you type `$`, it will be replaced with the word `money`? Also, since there is parenthesis, it makes a confusion about what output you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
  $(function() {
      $('.example').keyup(function(event) {
          if (event.which == 52) {  // "$"
              var rh = $(event.target);
              var newContent = rh.html().replace('$', 'Money');
              rh.html( newContent );
          }
      });
  });
</script>
<h5>Type "$" into the "here" section</h5>
<div class="example" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1">
  Please insert (here) now  
</div>
```

See this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kz2az869/2/).  I made it a little more jQuery-ish by replacing the `onkeypress` attribute with a jQuery event handler for class `example`.  I switched to `keyup` because until the key goes up the `$` does not appear in the contents of the `<div>` (such as for `keypress`).  When I did that, the code for `$` changes from 36 to 52.

Edit: fixed link to jsfiddle

Comment: I see what you did there. Thanks!